# Library to take part of image - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I wonder if there is library/tool which give possibility to client of app selecting part of an image and then app will have information (for example xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax) of this selected box?

I was looking through internet and didn't find anything. Is it easy to write it by yourself?